# How do I create an NSDictionary out of multilevel JSON using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: xcode, json, ios6, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

Example of JSON:

Note:  The "Docs" array is one of the many different arrays in this large 
array.

```
 {
        "Docs": {
            "Title1": {
                "id": "1",
                "active": "0",
                "title": "xxx",
                "date": "October 22, 2012",
                "description": "Description here",
                "ext": "DOCX",
                "when": "Tuesday, October 23",
                "subject": "French",
                "author": "xx xD",
                "email": "xx.xx@gmail.com",
                "day": "Tuesday, October 23",
                "dl": "9 downloads"
            },
            "Title2": {
                "id": "2",
                "active": "0",
                "title": "Vocab, Page 64",
                "date": "October 22, 2012",
                "description": "Description goes here",
                "ext": "XLSX",
                "when": "Tuesday October23",
                "subject": "French",
                "author": "xxxxxx",
                "email": "xxx@yahoo.com",
                "day": "Tuesday October23",
                "dl": "3 downloads"
            }
        }
```

How do I make an NSDictionary that gets the title of the "Docs" array (Docs) and also gets the count of the number of arrays in the docs array, for example?  Thanks. I am very confused in how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Once you get the deserialized data, you can iterate through the dictionary to read the elements. To get the count of number of objects:

```
// Get your object "Docs" from the root object
NSDictionary *dictionaryObject = (NSDictionary *)[JSON objectForKey:@"Docs"];

// Get the count by counting the keys
NSArray * allKeys = [dictionaryObject allKeys];
NSLog(@"Count : %d", [allKeys count]);
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for... The docs array was just an example.  I need to get the value of the names of all of the arrays in the big array...

Comment: @user1789040 [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) You've been given a good example to get you started. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Obviously Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  I have tried (successfully)getting data from a single array, but am not able to get it from a grouped array.

Comment: But it's not an array, or a grouped array. It's a NSDictionary containing other NSDictionaries.